# JComboBox.setSelectedItem doesn`t work

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a class Vehicle with Set of objects Part.
I am using that set to populate JComboBox like so:

```
Set<Part> parts = vehicle.getPart();
for(Part part : parts){
 jComboBox.addItem(part);
}
```

I have another class; Service with Part object in it.
I tried to

```
setSelectedItem(service.getPart());
```

But it doesn`t work. I also tried this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jComboBox.getItemCount(); i++){
 if(jComboBox.getItemAt(i) == service.getPart()){
  jComboBox.setSelectedIndex(i);
 }
else{
 System.out.println("Needed part is: " + service.getPart());
 System.out.println("Checked part is: " + jComboBox.getItemAt(i));
}
```

Still doesn`t work! 
Because toString for Part is overridden, i get output like this:

```
Needed part is: PartNumber1 / PartData1
Checked part is: PartNumber1 / PartData1


Needed part is: PartNumber1 / PartData1
Checked part is: PartNumber2 / PartData2


Needed part is: PartNumber1 / PartData1
Checked part is: PartNumber3 / PartData3

.equals(service.getPart())
```

...doesn`t work either.
I don`t understand what is the problem. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of the `Part` object?  Have you overridden the `equals` and `hashcode` methods? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I just tried to make simple program to mimic this problem but it works... I must be missing the bigger picture. Thank`s anyway. And no, i haven`t overridden equals or hashcode methods.

Answer (score 0):

Add output for .setSelectedIndex code branch. Seems it is never called.

Either
(a) replace all parts with strings (for debug purposes) or 
(b) implement equals+hashCode methods in your Part class. In both cases you should replace == with .equals() call.